# Is this website SSO authentication scheme safe?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on

I have designed a SSO scheme for the small collection of websites I have (some of them sub domains of main website).

I want all of the websites to use registration/login of the main site (and we can maintain full decoupling at the same time).

I want to see whether it is safe and if it can be made even simpler.

**Scenario:**

- Person clicks on login link on origin website (GET)
- Person's browser is brought to login URL along with origin website’s id ( https://authwebsiite.com/login/site/client-website-id )
- On authentication website we look up "encryption shared secret" and "return URL" in the database using "website id"
- Authentication is done on the authentication website
- User info (username and a few other items) is encrypted with the key origin website's owner has previously provided to the authentication website and the info is filled in a form and submitted back (POST) to origin website’s return  URL (https) using person's browser
- A session is created on origin website for the browser

**Concern:**

- Someone might simulate a return call…  (we used a shared secret i.e. encryption key to solve that)

**Improvements?**

- Can this process made even simpler?

Comment: Up until the last step, you've described openID. I'd strongly recommend following that (from [their RF](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html)) instead of rolling your own, as rolling your own on such a topic tends to be a risky, often unsafe endeavour.

Comment: Thanks. Implementing openID needs a lot of time... I am not sure I can invest that much of time... I need a very much easier method